# How can you detect a space in a text field in HTML

Tags: html

How can you detect if a space is entered in a text field in HTML, I found java script codes but they are not needed because I thought this was possible in HTML I tried using:

```
<input pattern="regexp">
```

But it did not work, So here is my code:

```
<form action="#">
 <div>
  <input type="text">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
 </div>
</form>
```

How Can I detect a space in the text field?

Comment: -1 just because honestly I can't see `<input pattern="regexp">` as an attempt to solve the problem but a _hint_ to ask a ready-to-use regex...

Comment: same as @AdrianoRepetti ... `<input pattern="regexp">` is no attempt at all and SO is not a free coding service

Answer (score 0):

The pattern `[^\s]*` matches all string without space.
When you submit your form, validation is performed and an error message is displayed if the input contains a space

```
<input type="text" name="text_without_space" pattern="[^\s]*" title="Title for text_without_space">
```

Comment: What If I want to check before submission?

Comment: When editing a red border is displayed on your field (if not validated).
If you want to see the message, either do javascript or submit the form